# Is there any way that I can automate vs code typing for specific file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation

What I'm looking for is a way to make vs code writes code automatically.. it's like vs code starts writing the code I provided in somehow by an extension or anything.

This could be useful when I start presenting a code to students!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found this awesome VS Code extension called [Auto-Type](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eeecomputes.auto-type) that can provide a code to it and start typing the code automatically.